# Difference or relationship between Homomorphisms and Tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

In the study of Cohomology the understanding of Tensor product is quite central. I am familiar with the definition and properties of the Tensor product, but I am struggling to find an intuitive decription of the Tensor product. Until now, I managed to somehow sneak by without ​a deeper understanding of the Tensor product, which now turns around to bite me. Those following questions may be answered already somewhere else, but I didn't manage to find any satisfactory formulation for me. So here it goes:

First, a bit of linear algebra: Lets say we have two finite-dimensional vectorspaces $V$ and $W$ over some field (might as well say $\mathbb{R}$). Then we can construct a basis for $V \otimes W$ by $\{ v_i \otimes w_j \}_{i,j}$, where $\{v_i\}_i$ and $\{w_j\}_j$ are bases for $V$ and $W$. So if we take an element $x \in V \otimes W$ we can write it as a linear combinations of those basis elements. Ordering the coefficients in a Matrix, they describe an Element in $Hom(V,W)$. For example if $V=W= \mathbb{R}^2$ with standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$, then the tensor $e_1 \otimes e_1$ + $e_2 \otimes e_2$ can be seen as the identity Homomorphism. So to me it doesn't seem so far fetched that there is some connection between $V \otimes W$ and $Hom(V,W)$.

So far so good. Now consider two free and finitely generated abelian groups $H$ and $G$. We can view those as two free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so we can tensor $H \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}} G$. Moreover, this tensor product is free and finitely generated abelian itself, by building a basis as in the linear algebra case. Also in similar fashion, one should be able to identify elements of the tensor product as group-homomorphisms between $H$ and $G$, right?

This is the point where all intuition or description begins to fail for me. Here are some scenarios:

1. In the linear algebra case, when the vectorspaces are no longer finite-dimensional, is it still possible to somehow get this duality between tensor product and the space of homomorphisms?
2. In the case of abelian groups, one can drop the finitely generated and/or the free part. In the latter part, even the basis argument now fails to work. But is it still possible to get some kind of relation between $H \otimes G$ and $Hom(H,G)$? If so, can I somehow "embed" one space into the other? And if any connection between the two spaces is lost, why is it lost and is there some other "intuitive space" or "intuitive formulation" for elements in the Tensor product?
3. Applying all this to (co-)homology, lets say we have a space $X$ and its singular chain complex $S.(X)$. One can take coefficients in any abelian group G by defining $S.(X;G) = S.(X) \otimes G$, and cochains as $S^p(X;G) = Hom(S_p(X), G)$. So if the above identification always works, there would be "no difference" between homology with coefficients and cohomology (at least on the chain level, since in (co-)homology one takes different quotients). Also we have the Universal coefficients theorem, which gives some insight on how those two objects are connected. I know the statements, how they work and how to apply them. But they "don't make sense" on an intuitive level, which for me fails on the level of tensors. Also for example in the universal coefficients theorem. It says that it matters if I first tensor the chain complex with the group and then take homology, or if I take Homology and then tensor with the group. But why (intuitively)?

I want to clarify that I am in no way confusing Tensor products with Homomorphisms and it is clear that they are seperate spaces and contain different elements. But both objects seem to be really closely related, I just can't put my finger on it. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesnt. I understand why it doesn't work but I don't *understand* why it doesnt work (if that makes sense). At least for me, the homomorphisms are the way easier object to grasp, so I hope to understand the tensor products better by linking them to the Homomorphisms. So I don't really have a clear question but any input on an intuitive description of the tensor product would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, then $V^* \otimes W \cong Hom(V, W)$, and of course if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic (but not in a particularly nice way). I think this is part of what you're seeing. For abelian groups, the corresponding statement would be an isomorphism between $Hom(H, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes G$ and $Hom(H, G)$, but that frequently fails; for example if $H$ if finite, then $Hom(H, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

There are other connections between the tensor product and Hom, in particular the [adjunction relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction):
$$
Hom(A, Hom(B, C)) \cong Hom(A \otimes B, C).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense. But I'd be interested in the Isomorphism for $Hom(H, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes G$ and $Hom(H,G)$. Is there some "weak" condition that this holds? If $H$ and $G$ are free and finitely generated abelian this would for sure work. But how about if $H$ is free (and maybe finitely generated) abelian, and $G$ is some commutative ring, not necessarily free or finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$? Because this is a frequent case in cohomology

Comment: There is an obvious map $Hom(H, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes G \to Hom(H, G)$, sending a basic tensor $f \otimes g$ to the map $h \mapsto f(h) g$. It looks like it should be an isomorphism if $H=\mathbb{Z}$, and therefore if $H$ is finitely generated free. Maybe it's even true for arbitrary free abelian $H$. I think it should be true without any conditions on $G$ — the burden should be on $H$. In my post, I don't think I needed to assume that $W$ was finite dimensional, only $V$.